# checking if deployment successfull or not powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet, azure-rm-template

I have a `powershell` which deploys some artifacts to azure. I ask the user for the below values which are defined the template parameter file.

**1.** functionapp Name: `$functionAppName` 
 **2.** Function App Service Plan: `$functionApp_appServicePlanName` 
 **3.** Event Hub Namespace Name: `$eventHubNamespaceName`
 **4.** Storage Account Name: `$storageAccountName`
 **5.** Event Hub Namespace name: `$eventHubNamespaceName`

I need to test whether the resources are successfully getting created in the portal. For that i have used the below script to check if its created or not.

*if its created, its fine the script can continue.*

*if its not, I want to prompt the user to enter a value for that failed resource again and recreate it.*

How do I do it ?

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Enter below values for deployment"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter Function App name: ' -NoNewline
$functionAppName = Read-Host
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter Function App Service plan name: ' -NoNewline
$functionApp_appServicePlanName = Read-Host
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
while ($true) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter Event Hub Namespace name: ' -NoNewline
    $eventHubNamespaceName = Read-Host
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Checking whether the entered name for Event Hub Namespace is available"
    $availability = Test-AzureRmEventHubName -Namespace $eventHubNamespaceName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameAvailable
    if ($availability -eq $true) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Entered Event Hub Namespace name is available"
        break
    }
    Write-Host "Enter valid Event Hub Namespace name"
}
while ($true) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter Storage account name: ' -NoNewline
    $storageAccountName = Read-Host 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Checking whether the entered name for Storage account is available"
    $availability = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name $storageAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameAvailable
    if ($availability -eq $true ) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Entered Storage account name is available"
        break
    }
    Write-Host "Enter valid Storage account name"
}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter Event Hub name: ' -NoNewline
$eventHubName = Read-Host
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -functionAppName $functionAppName -functionApp_appServicePlanName $functionApp_appServicePlanName -eventHubNamespaceName $eventHubNamespaceName -storageAccountName $storageAccountName -eventHubName $eventHubName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName ` -TemplateFile azuredeploy.json ` -TemplateParameterFile azuredeploy.parameters.json
if(Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SiteName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    "Found"
}
else {
    "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: So do you want help with determining if the deployment was successful or with how to prompt the user?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: There are two questions in my comment. Which is right? Or are they both right?

Comment: i want to prompt if deployment is failed , so ideally Both

Comment: @EBGreen any help ?

Comment: Start with determining if the deployment was successful. Did you look at Get-AzureDeployment?

Comment: Yes i did , can't seem to get it work

Comment: Then you need to update your question with that information. Waht exactly did you try. How exactly did it not work. Were there errors? No output at all? Wrong output? What parameters did you use. "It didn't work" is never enough information to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Gets details of a deployment:

```
Get-AzureDeployment
   [-ServiceName] <String>
   [[-Slot] <String>]
   [-Profile <AzureSMProfile>]
   [-InformationAction <ActionPreference>]
   [-InformationVariable <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

more Details in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azuredeployment) or insert into your Powershell:

```
get-help Get-AzureDeployment -ShowWindow
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? with a example ? i don't get how this is useful to my question

Comment: Open your Powershell and insert: get-help Get-AzureDeployment -ShowWindow